# How to limit the text characters in the text input box depending on option chosen

Tags: html, text, shopify, variant

Hi I am fairly new to coding and definitely a newbie. I am using shopify and trying to edit some of the code. I am trying to limit the text characters someone can enter into a text box depending on the option they chose. Currently i have a drop down tab where customers selects either 1-5 letters  OR 6 letters OR 7 Letters. I would like that if they select 1-5 letters they cannot input 6 characters into the text box. The same should apply if they chose another option. I do not like the idea of having multiple text input boxes. I want the same input box but for it to change the amount of characters it accepts depending on the option chosen.
I hope this makes sense :)
Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, have you tried anything yet and if you did, could you post a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

You must use javascript for that purpose. Actually for having dynamic frontend you must use javascript. It doesn't matter if you do it with vanilla javascript, JQuery or other libraries and frameworks.
I suggest you to google "javascript". And you can use w3schools.com to learn it.